# Windows 10 intermittent mouse and keyboard freeze

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, freeze

I've tried asking this question on other forums, only to get "reinstall your drivers" followed by a dozen "doesn't work" responses. Stackoverflow is my last resort.

Very stock Dell XPS 8930 running Windows 10. All it is used for is Chrome, Zoom, and to RDP into my work laptop. Sometimes I listen to music. Intermittently the mouse point stops moving and keyboard input is lost. After a few seconds (sometimes more than a few), the pointer will jump (as if all the mouse events were suddenly received) but the keyboard events are gone. I might go an hour or two, or even a day, without this happening or it might happen several times over a relatively short period. It happens when no apps other than Chrome (which is always running) are open.

I've been scouring the Internet since I got the machine, reading dozens of posts, and I have not found a single suggestion as to what could be happening other than "bad drivers". I've verified my driver installation. Most of the posts are followed by "me too" comments stating the reinstalling drivers didn't work.

Comment: Can you use a different browser for a day or two to prove that Chrome is not the cause?

Comment: Are you using a wireless keyboard and mouse?

Comment: What are your mouse model and driver? Have you tried another mouse?

Comment: Are you connected to a high-speed network and transferring a lot of data at the time this occurs? The PC might not be able to keep up with data and keyboard/mouse interrupts. BTW, if you allow your PC to download Windows Updates for *other* PC's on the system, that could add to the load.